# error: 'gzoffset' was not declared in this scope

Tags: zlib

I want to compile a program on a remote server (without the root access). I get the error below:

```
error: 'gzoffset' was not declared in this scope
```

I believe it's related to the 'zlib' that I have installed on the server, but apparently, the compiler (gcc 4.9.2) cannot find it.

Any comment will be highly appreciated.